# Taking the derivative with respect to more than one variable?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions, derivatives, partial-derivative

I was wondering if it is possible to take the derivative of a function with respect to more than one variable. In other words, I am wondering if $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial (x,y)},\frac{\partial f}{\partial (x,z)}\frac{\partial f}{\partial (y,z)}...$$(where the denominator represents the pair of variables we are differentiating with respect to) exist, and if so if they have any use. Also, do these derivatives have a special name? One important detail is that the function $f$ must be dependent on more variables then the amount of variables it is being differentiated with respect to.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative

Comment: @AndrewZhang This is a partial answer since it is with respect to all variables.

Comment: You can just take $g(x_1,\dots,x_r) = f(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ with $r\leq n$, so there is no issue.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial (x,y)}$$?

Comment: When I use that notation (for any number of variables), I intend a matrix whose columns are the respective partial derivatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you  can. For example, if $z,h \in \mathbb C \text { and} f: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$, we can take the limit  $$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}$$ if such a limit exists. Writing $h=x+iy;x,y \in \mathbb R$, we are, in effect, taking the limit in terms of the real variables $x \text{ and }y$.